# Is void safety implemented in C?

Tags: c, void

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_safety),

> Void safety is a guarantee within an **object-oriented programming
>   language** that no object references will have null or void values

That's all good and true, however C is not an object-oriented PL, and the definition only applies to the derefencing of null pointers or references to object instances.

So, is there void safety in C or not? Can the term (or its opposite) even be applicable to describe the language?

Comment: Did you ever manage to dereference an invalid pointer in C?

Comment: No, Basically you need to check the pointer whether the pointer is NULL of not and then you can deference the pointer.

Comment: @rabishaw Then you *may* be able to de-reference the pointer. It not being NULL us no guarantee that it points somewhere sensible.

Comment: @  juanchopanza ... NULL checking is for safety purpose... if the pointer doesn't point to anywhere /or doesn't have any value and you try to deference it .. it will cause crash right?

Comment: @rabishaw Your first comment was suggesting it is safe to de-reference a pointer as long it is not NULL. I was adding a clarification to that.

Comment: There is no such guarantee that if the pointer is not NULL then you will get the expected thing.... but i want to say that NULL checking is the initial thing that we need to do....

Comment: There's no such safety in C. Is very much coding with the stabilisers off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. But nor is there in the C++ (one of the object-oriented programming languages) if you use pointers. C++ *references* are the things that are supposed to always refer to a real object, pointers can be NULL in both C and C++. You may be able to *get* dangling references in C++ but, as undefined behaviour, you've broken the rules and all bets are off.

C itself *has* no references, only pointers, and you don't get that level of protection at all, unless you manually do it yourself:

```
if (ptr != NULL)
    doSomethingWith (*ptr);
```

In C, code like:

```
char *xyzzy = NULL;
char plugh = *xyzzy;
```

is just *asking* for trouble but the compiler won't stop you from doing it because it's perfectly legal (though, as for the C++ case, undefined behaviour).

Comment: And even in C++ we can have dangling references (though we have to try a bit harder).

Comment: @5gon12eder: good point, made my statement a little less emphatic.

Comment: @5gon12eder But then they wouldn't have "null or void" values. That implies that, in order not to guarantee void safety, the language has such concepts, and that the references can hold them. That covers most programming languages I can think of.

Comment: You can't have null/dangling references in C++ unless the program has already triggered undefined behaviour (at which point it's no longer covered by the rules of C++ , including any rules relating to "void safety")

Answer (score 0):

There is no NULL safety in C. There are no references in C, just pointers. Pointers can be set to NULL, and deref'ing a NULL ptr can cause a segmentation fault as exemplified:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int val = 5555;
    int val2 = 555;


    int *ptr;

    ptr = &val; /* ptr now points to the address of val */

    printf("Address: 0x%.8x [0x%.8x]", &ptr, &val);

    printf("\nAddress: 0x%.8x [0x%.8x]", ptr, &val);

    printf("\nValue: %d [%d]", *ptr, val);  



    ptr = &val2;

    printf("\n\n\nNew Address: 0x%.8x [0x%.8x]", &ptr, &val2);

    printf("\nNew Address: 0x%.8x [0x%.8x]", ptr, &val2);

    printf("\nNew Value: %d [%d]\n\n", *ptr, val2);


    ptr = NULL;

    printf("\nptr = %d", ptr);

    printf("\n&ptr = 0x%.8x", &ptr);

    // printf("\n*ptr = %d", *ptr); /* causes segfault */

    return 0;
}
```

**char@char:~$** ./a.out

Address: 0xf8638e50 [0xf8638e5c]

Address: 0xf8638e5c [0xf8638e5c]

Value: 5555 [5555]

New Address: 0xf8638e50 [0xf8638e58]

New Address: 0xf8638e58 [0xf8638e58]

New Value: 555 [555]

ptr = 0

&ptr = 0xf8638e50

---

but if you uncomment that last call to printf you get:

---

**char@char:~$** ./a.out

Address: 0xfbb6cae0 [0xfbb6caec]

Address: 0xfbb6caec [0xfbb6caec]

Value: 5555 [5555]

New Address: 0xfbb6cae0 [0xfbb6cae8]

New Address: 0xfbb6cae8 [0xfbb6cae8]

New Value: 555 [555]

ptr = 0

Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to guarantee that no object references have null or void values when there are no object references (e.g. in C).

It would be correct to say that C has void safety, but it would also be meaningless. For more information, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth